# Software evaluation - licence

Tags: qt, licensing, visual-c++

Can any one help me on software licence module.
We created a new application and want to release a demo version(30 days trial) of our tool later we need full version.
How can i generate license file or license code and how to limit 30 days evaluation.
Please give me some help on this.

Our application is developed on windows in QT

Comment: What is the relation to patents?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. See here and here for details, and the help center for more.

Answer (score 6):

There could be several possibilities:

- Timestamp and encrypt the date of installation somewhere safe(registry or an external encrypted file)
- Upon each run, validate the registry date as well as the system date.
- User may tamper with system date/time; so you may would want to validate the system date/time wrt previous run date/time, and plan you app's actions accordingly.
- Show the app-dormant error message upon currentDate - installationDate > 30, and provide a link to your online registration page.

You may also require to:

- Develop a keygen(`key encryptor`) that would generate(a hash out of a certain key) the serial key.
- Add the `key decrytor` in your product that, upon getting the key from user input, would `try` to generate the same(hash?) key and compare that hash with your decryptor algo.

Checkout [this](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/index.php?showtopic=137990) and [this](http://www.vijaymukhi.com/documents/books/vsnet/chap4.htm) that uses `SerialNumberTemplate` to get serial number during installation.

--EDIT--

You can note the time either from:

- The **date of installation**: Create a [Custom Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9k65z2d.aspx#Mtps_DropDownFilterText) in your visual studio setup project; and add registry item in `Install` override method.
- The **date from first-run**: Use `DateTime.Now.Date` to get the current date and encrypt/save it somewhere, [probably registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e7chcf.aspx).

Comment: Thanks dude... Nice information.

Comment: My problem is hoe to capture the date and time during my first installation. How to give that to my program

Comment: @sijith: Please see my updated post. Also, as a side note, it is always good to post questions in a separate thread; that helps helpers as well as those looking for help (0:

Answer (score 3):

Although I don't see the connection to patents it's as easy as that:

- Save the installation time
- at any startup check whether 30 days are reached
- provide a mechanism to unlock the software eith a license key

Comment: thaks 4 ur valuable information.
May i know how can i access system time during installation.
How to capture timer during installation.

Comment: qt provides time functions. If your installation environment is something else you should name it and or browse the documentation for things like that.