# MAke package for Qt application

Tags: qt4, package

How can we make package for Qt application. I want to make a package which will be like normal software & install like that.
& If I want to add the license key feature in the application how I will do that? The license key will be used when use want the full feature of the application.

Comment: two totally unrelated questions in 1  and packaging question lacks any sort of information about which platform you are targetting your software for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are literally hundreds of installer creators out there (assuming Windows here).

I personally like http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php

Creating a 'feature unlock' key is a totally different question, and not one with a straight-forward answer.

Perhaps a good start is looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491609/software-evaluation-licence). You might get better answers if you make your question a little more detailed.

Comment: yes the installer package is working..i can create the exe files. thanks